# Bash, grep, whole line as variable

Tags: bash, grep, sed

**Issue**

How can I store whole line output from `grep` as 1 variable, not for every string.

Example (I need just 3 variables, whole lines).

```
user@local:~/bin/kb$ grep -E '##.*bash.*file.*add' bash.kb
## bash, file, add string behind founded string
## bash, files, add string to begin
## bash, file, add comma to end of line except last line
user@local:~/bin/kb$
```

But `for` example.

```
user@local:~/bin/kb$ for i in $(grep -E '##.*bash.*file.*add' bash.kb); do echo $i; done
##
bash,
file,
add
string
behind
founded
string
##
bash,
files,
add
string
to
begin
##
bash,
file,
add
comma
to
end
of
line
except
last
line
user@local:~/bin/kb$
```

I need this (only 3 variables as whole line).

```
1st variable $i[0] = '## bash, file, add string behind founded string'
2nd variable $i[1] = '## bash, files, add string to begin'
3rd variable $i[2] = '## bash, file, add comma to end of line except last line'
```

How can I do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is that

```
for i in $(grep -E '##.*bash.*file.*add' bash.kb); do echo $i; done
```

iterates over whitespace-delimited *words* in the command output. This is sometimes referred to as *word splitting* or more generally as *split + glob*.

You can read lines into an *indexed array* in bash using `mapfile` (or its synonym, `readarray`). Because `mapfile` reads from standard input, replace the command substitution `$( ... )` with a process substitution `<( ... )`:

```
mapfile -t var < <(grep -E '##.*bash.*file.*add' bash.kb)
```

You can retrieve the values using `"${var[0]}"`,`"${var[1]}"` etc. (arrays  are zero-based) or loop over them all using

```
for i in "${var[@]}"; do echo "$i"; done
```

Note the use of double quotes to prevent word-splitting within the array elements.

---

If you don't actually need variables at all, and simply want to loop over the *lines* of command output, then use a `while` loop in place of a `for` loop:

```
while read -r i; do
  echo "$i"
done < <(grep -E '##.*bash.*file.*add' bash.kb)
```

Comment: Thanks. And how can I do some cycle for these outputs? `for i in $(mapfile -t var < <(grep -E '##.*bash.*file.*add' bash.kb)); do echo $i; done` shows me nothing.

Comment: @genderbee I've added a prototype loop above

Comment: Thanks! Yes, `while` command should be in my next comment. :)